# Angularjs dynamically create models

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looping through a result set and dynamically creating model values, such as:

```
     angular.forEach(users, function(user) {
           $scope.usersModels.online[user.id] = 0;
           $scope.usersModels.online[user.id]['checked'] = 'checked';
           $scope.$watch('usersModels.online[user.id]', function(val) {
                  console.log(val);

           });
     });
```

I'm also trying to watch the change of these models and get the value.  This doesn't work however, any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
angular.forEach(users, function(user) {
       $scope.usersModels.online[user.id] = {};
       $scope.usersModels.online[user.id]['value']   = 0;
       $scope.usersModels.online[user.id]['checked'] = 'checked';
       $scope.$watch(function() {
            return $scope.usersModels.online[user.id]['value'];
       }, function(val) {
            console.log(val);
       });
 });
```

Comment: try removing the '' from $watch

Comment: OR

$scope.$watch('userModels.online.' + user.id, ...});

Comment: or use function as first argument to $watch.
$scope.$watch(function () { return $scope.usersModels.online[user.id] }, /* handler */)

Comment: @dave - I think the way you use $watch() is fine. Before we look at the cause of your problem, I want to point out that the way you assign object references in the code does not make sense. Assuming we have a user id of 1. `$scope.usersModels.online[1] = 0;` implies the property is pointing a primitive type, 0. But then comes `$scope.usersModels.online[user.id]['checked'] = 'checked';` and all the sudden you are treating the same property as if it was an object , which has a property named `checked`. It could very well be a typo. Either way, please have that fixed first.

Comment: Here is a [quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fp6Ju/) that illustrates what I said above.

Comment: @tamakisquare - Good find! I didn't notice that, I updated it in my post.

Comment: @Artem - Thanks, that seems to be watching correctly now

Comment: In my view, I use `{{usersModel.online[user.id].checked}}` in a input field.  You can see I'm setting it to 'checked', but this doesn't seem to put 'checked' in the box, as it's unchecked.  Any idea if this is related to my use of objects?  Thanks so much

Comment: We would need to see more code to help with that.  Is your forEach loop inside an $http success callback, or some 3rd-party AJAX callback?  If the latter, $apply() is needed.  Is usersModel.online[user.id].checked defined when the view is first rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided does not give us a complete picture. Some of the missing pieces are:

- The code for populating the `users` object
- The view code that shows how you bind the inputs to the models

Hence, I need to make some assumptions:

- The code for populating the `users` object is not the cause of the problem.
- The input that binds to the `checked` property is a checkbox.

With the assumptions in mind, one immediate problem I find in your code is that you assign a string value, `"checked"`, to the `checked` property when you should be using a boolean value. Two-way binding for checkbox input works with boolean value only.

Since I don't get to see the complete picture, it's hard for me to say if that's the only problem with your code. Based on the information you have given, I created a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HwcxwMv7sU9904fjzhXr?p=preview). Note that I simply assigned an object of three user ids to generate the `users` object with the assumption made above. Compare it to your code and identify other possible problems, if any. Please be sure to report back if you found other errors in your code, as it might do good for new comers.